# No key events for minus and point in Android number input

Tags: android, keylistener

I have a EditText field with input type signed decimal and registered a key listener to it.

Now I get the events for numbers and delete, but no events for minus and decimal points.

How can I receive events when minus or decimal point key is pressed?

---

Here is what I did:

In layout (`activity_edit.xml`):

```
<EditText
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal" />
```

In `EditActivity.java`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle stored) {
    super.onCreate(stored);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);
    //[...]
    amount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount);
    amount.setOnKeyListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.d(LOGTAG, "onKey event: " + event);
    return false;
}
```

When I press a number or delete I will get events like this with logcat:

```
onKey event: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_2, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x6, repeatCount=0,...
onKey event: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_1, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x6, repeatCount=0,...
onKey event: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_DEL, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x6, repeatCount=0,...
```

but no events when I press `-` or `.`

Answer (score 0):

I could work around this problem by using a `TextWatcher` instead of a `OnKeyListener`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle stored) {
    super.onCreate(stored);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);
    //[...]
    amount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount);
    amount.addTextChangedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Text in amount is " + s.toString());
}
```